# Accessing jQuery returned value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I'm trying to access the returned value and add a check of `.contains` so I can know if I need to reload the page or not. I've been trying to do something like the following:

```
alert(msg.d);
if(msg.d.contains("deleted"))
    location.reload();
```

The returned object is a string.

It does show me the alert message, but won't reload the page once it's necessary. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: `msg.d.indexOf("deleted") > -1`

Comment: Well, what have you found out debugging your code? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Are you expecting an array or object back for `msg.d`?

Comment: Also, without know what the data type/value of `msg.d` is, every answer you get is just a guess.

Comment: @FelixKling - it is implied that `deleted` is a top level property of the returned object, but you are correct that the OP did not specify the returned object's hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `.contians()` method, You need to use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

> The `indexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

*Code*

```
if(msg.d.indexOf("deleted") > -1)
    location.reload();
```

Comment: @OmerAviv - `indexOf()` is an ECMA-Script 5 and later construct, so if you need to support pre-ES5 browsers (IE 8 or earlier), then you can use a polyfill like the one [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's `hasOwnProperty` function, like this:

```
if(msg.d.hasOwnProperty("deleted") {
    location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
if( /deleted/.test(msg.d) ) {
    location.reload();
}
```